# How can i insert a record in a specific field using a button?

Tags: php, html

I'm new to php and i need help on how to put buttons in every row of the table and insert a record in the "status" field that says "claimed" whenever i click that button. I'm currently working on a lost and found monitoring system for a school project. Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "lfms");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT itemid, item, quantity, name, place, status FROM lfmstable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>" . $row["itemid"]. "</td>
                <td>" . $row["item"]. "</td>
                <td>" . $row["quantity"]. "</td>
                <td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row["place"]. "</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: need more clarification

Comment: Where do you output the `<table>` tag to start the table

Comment: @Dilek There are NO parameters in that query, so there is no need to prepare and bind because there is NOTHING to bind to anything :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly My ipad was frozen so I couldnt write, Take a tour to prepared statements, in to comment . lol